# Why do I get “Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to User” when trying to insert an INT in FOREIGN KEY using EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core in a .NET Core Winforms app. I want to insert an INT as foreign key but I get an error

```
  namespace FTAS
    {
   public partial class SecurityQuestion : Form
        {
   
    public user users;
    
    
    public SecurityQuestion(LoginForm loginForm, user userdata)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.users = userdata;
        
        
    }
   
    private void BtnSubmitQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsValid())
        {
            var context = new FtasDbContext();

            context.SQuestion.Add(new Entity.SQuestions
            {
                Question = Questioncombo.Text,
                Answer = TxtQuestionAns.Text,
                User = users.Id

            }) ;

            context.SaveChanges();

        }

    }

   

    private bool IsValid()
    {
        if (Questioncombo.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
      if (TxtQuestionAns.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

}
}
```

But here is core for Table User **INT**

```
 namespace FTAS.Entity
 {
    [Table("User")]
   public class user
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public string Name { get; set; }


    public string FatherName { get; set; }


    public long Cnic { get; set; }


    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public long Mob { get; set; }

   


    public string Email { get; set; }


    public string Username { get; set; }


    public string Password { get; set; }


    public string Designation { get; set; }    


    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

  
    
}
    
}
```

Then why i get Error **CS0029   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'FTAS.Entity.user'**

I'm also try to
private user int32(int id)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
and change
**User = int32(users.Id)**

then i get the error

**'The method or operation is not implemented.'**

**The Code for Entity.SQuestion**

```
  class SQuestions
  {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }


    public string Answer { get; set; }
   
    public user User { get; set; }

    
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add source code for  Entity.SQuestions ? The problem could be there.

Comment: You get the 'The method or operation is not implemented.' because your code throws a NotImplementedException.

Comment: You are trying to insert an `int` into type `user`. Did you mean to do `user.Id = users.Id`?

Comment: @janzen           User is a attribute of SQuestion that is Foreign Key

Comment: @Russ          Any solution ... ?

Comment: shouldn't be User = new User{Id=users.Id}

Comment: Hi @Hamza Tariq - Ht Khan,just delete the line `User = users.Id`

Comment: @Yinqiu its Working ... but problem is that  FOREIGN KEY is **NULL** after submit data ...
i need to story FOREIGN KEY of Other Table value that is **INT** as well QSuestion.

Comment: Hi @Hamza Tariq - Ht Khan,does this solution helpful?

Comment: @Yinqiu yeah is help to solve 1 problem but it's works as this Code **User= users**  

But now **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:** 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.' 
**Inner Exception SqlException:** Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. then i get is Exception at context.SaveChanges(); in that Form where from i open SQuestion Form ... mean 1st SQuestion Form oen .. but when i submit Data ... Inner Exception SqlException comes in Previous Form

Comment: If you only want to store foreign key, you shouldnt need to store whole user in SQuestions. Change it to int User and store nothing but user.id.

Comment: @Saplu Solved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this code
namespace FTAS.Entity
{
class SQuestions
{
public long Id { get; set; }

```
    public string Question { get; set; }


    public string Answer { get; set; }
   
    public user User { get; set; }
    
   }
  }
```

Change

```
public user User { get; set; }
```

To

```
public user User { get; set; } 
[ForeignKey("User")]
public int UserFK { get; set; }
```

And Solved the Problem

Answer (score 0):

Property User in class SQuestions is a type "user",  which is no the same type as users.Id, which is a type int.  Assignments must be of the same type.

Change:

```
User = users.Id
```

to:

```
User = users
```

Comment: **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:** 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

**Inner Exception** SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

then i get is Exception at **context.SaveChanges();**